# '+' disappears on databinding in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-binding

When I try to post this email : "name+1@domain.com" I get "name 1@domain.com" in my Model's property in the controller. Anyone know what I can do so the '+' will not disappear?

Thanks

Edited :

Ok I think I did not give enough explication :

I have a form that allow my users to search for members by different properties, one of them is Email. In the current system I have members that the email is using '+' inside the string. (like this : name+1@domain.com) When I try to search for this user using his email, the value that is posted to my controller does not contains the '+' so it results as 'name 1@domain.com' and the search do not return anything.

I'm pretty sure it's something about the encoding but I don't use any link here, I post a full SearModel witch contains a string property named "Email" witch is automatically bind to my Textbox with the same name in my view.

Can a Specify to encode a property of a Model object?

Thanks again!

Here's my Model :

```
public class SearchMemberModel
{
    [LocalizedDisplayName("MemberNumber")]
    public string MemberNumber { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("ActiveOnly")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller's action :

```
public virtual ActionResult ListAjax(SearchMemberModel search)
    {
        var gridModel = new GridModel<SerializableMember>();
        var data = _session.All<Member>();
        if (search != null)
        {
            if (search.Active) data = data.Where(x => x.Active);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Email)) data = data.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(search.Email));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.FirstName)) data = data.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(search.FirstName));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.LastName)) data = data.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(search.LastName));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.MemberNumber)) data = data.Where(x => x.MemberNumber.Contains(search.MemberNumber));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Phone)) data = data.Where(x => x.Phone.Contains(search.Phone));
        }

        var list = new List<SerializableMember>(data.Count());
        list.AddRange(data.ToList().Select(obj => new SerializableMember(obj)));
        gridModel.Data = list;
        return View(gridModel);
    }
```

And the view (taught it was not necessary) :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Enquete.Models.SearchMemberModel>" %>
```

<%:Resources.TitleMemberList %>

### <%:Resources.TitleMemberList %>

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><%: Resources.Search %></legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberNumber) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MemberNumber) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberNumber) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="<%: Resources.ToSearch %>" id="btnSearch" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

 <%= Html.Telerik().Grid<SerializableMember>()
                .Name("Grid")
                .Columns(colums =>
                 {
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Email).Title(Resources.Email).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.Action(MVC.Member.Edit()) + "/<#=Id#>\" ><#=Email#></a>");
                     colums.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Title(Resources.FirstName);
                     colums.Bound(c => c.LastName).Title(Resources.LastName);
                     colums.Bound(c => c.MemberNumber).Title(Resources.MemberNumber);
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Phone).Title(Resources.Phone);
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Active).Title(Resources.Active).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<img src=\"Content/images/icons/<#=Active#>.png\" alt=\"<#=Active#>\" />");
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.Action(MVC.Member.ResetPassword()) + "/<#=Id#>\" title=\"" + Resources.ResetPassword + "\" >" + Resources.ResetPassword + "</a>");
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.Action(MVC.Member.Activate()) + "/<#=Id#>\" title=\"" + Resources.Activate + "\" >" + Resources.Activate + "</a>");
                     colums.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" }).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"" + Url.Action(MVC.Member.Deactivate()) + "/<#=Id#>\" title=\"" + Resources.Deactivate + "\" >" + Resources.Deactivate + "</a>");
                 })
                .DataBinding(d => d.Ajax().Select(MVC.Member.ListAjax(Model).GetRouteValueDictionary()))
                .Sortable()
                .NoRecordsTemplate(Resources.NoData)
        %>
        <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
                    var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
                    var searchModel = {
                        MemberNumber: $('#MemberNumber').val(),
                        Email: $('#Email').val(),
                        FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
                        LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                        Phone: $('#Phone').val(),
                        Active: $('#Active').is(':checked')
                    };
                    grid.rebind(searchModel);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

        <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(g => g.DefaultPath("~/Content/Javascript/2010.3.1110"))%>
```

Comment: You posted your model and your controller action but you forgot to post the most important part: your view, the part which is responsible for generating the urls. Your routing configuration might also be useful.

Comment: After your numerous updates it seems that you are using Telerik controls now. All this is important information that you should have provided in your initial question. I don't know those controls. I know ASP.NET MVC and I know that query string parameters should be URL encoded. Maybe someone knowing those controls might shed some light. I strongly suspect that `grid.rebind(searchModel);` is doing something wrong. Try url encoding: `Email: encodeURIComponent($('#Email').val()),`. Normally this should have been handled by the controls but who knows, I've seen many shitty code.

Comment: There you go, I taught it was not necessary since it's a simple form that post using strongly typed view. But I just realized(remembered) that I do my post using AJAX with Telerik's grid function rebind() so I get an url with "+" not encoded. Now I need to figure out how to encode this. Thanks!

Comment: does using an explicit `encodeURIComponent` solve your problem?

Comment: @Darin Yes I've posted my comment before I saw yours, thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you need to url encode it: `name%2B1%40domain.com`. `+` in a url means white space. Notice also that you need to url encode `@` to `%40` because it also has special meaning.

Conclusion: always url encode your urls. Always use Url helpers to generate urls. Never hardcode urls.

---

UPDATE:

Try:

```
var searchModel = {
    MemberNumber: encodeURIComponent($('#MemberNumber').val()),
    Email: encodeURIComponent($('#Email').val()),
    FirstName: encodeURIComponent($('#FirstName').val()),
    LastName: encodeURIComponent($('#LastName').val()),
    Phone: encodeURIComponent($('#Phone').val()),
    Active: $('#Active').is(':checked')
};
```

Comment: +1 for always encoding, which is also a security aspect for avoiding injection problems...

Comment: It works, thanks for the quick replies and sorry for not posting all my code at first time. I will also open a tickets on telerik's support so they fix this up.

Comment: @VinnyG, yeah at your place I would also open a ticket. What a crap money can buy :-)

Comment: Telerik also has an open source version of their MVC controls : http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/ witch can, sometimes, be timesaver ;)

Comment: @VinnyG, thanks, that's good to know. By the way I won some free licences from Telerik thanks to my reputation on SO but I never really had some time to look at their controls. Questions like yours make me put a big red cross in my mind about their products and especially I would think twice before recommending them to someone who asks me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the browser eating it up. Check the actual output of your code instead of looking at your browser status bar.

If you want an actual +, you might need to URL encode it (replace it with `%2B`, although you might want to consider other characters as well).